# Why use of / in preg_match() function php

Tags: php, regex

Experimenting with regex in php. Could someone explain why the regex `"/^[^0-9][A-Z]$/"` has to begin and end with a forward slash? Is this because this is how regex are started and ended?

```
<?php

$string1 = "aA";

if(preg_match("/^[^0-9][A-Z]$/",$string1)){
    echo "Match";
}else{
    echo "No Match";
}

?>
```

Comment: *"Could someone explain why the regex "/^[^0-9][A-Z]$/" has to begin and end with a forward slash?"* - Who said the delimiter "has" to be a slash? I'd sure like to know that. Or did "you" think that it had to?

Comment: Personally, I feel the question is too broad and there are a few reasons why the choice of delimiter could make a difference.

Comment: TL;DR: The P in PCRE is for Perl, and not even the Perl guys have much of an explanation for why delimiters are a thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please read http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php. One does not have to stick to //, can be ##, or ++, %%, etc. But yes, those are delimiters for regex.

Comment: thanks a lot couldn't find this because I didn't know where to look for ;)

Answer (score 1):

You are correct. The [MDN page on RegEx](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) is a good overview. But bear in mind this is JavaScript specific info and actual results may vary based on the language used. In other words, not all languages use or require the slashes, but many do.

Answer (score 1):

In answer to the OP's last question, yes, *by default* a regular expression or regex in PHP starts and ends with a forward slash delimiter. As to the previous question, let's consider what a regex represents.  It consists of a special kind of string "...  which defines a set of one or more strings of characters."; see [here](http://math.mercyhurst.edu/~griff/courses/mis180/Lectures/regex.pdf). In C, Python and Java according to this [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Delimiters), a literal string may be used without delimiters.

Perl, a predecessor of PHP uses delimiters for such pattern matching strings and by default employs the forward slash as a delimiter. PHP adopted this practice, too.  However, these defaults may be modified.  PHP allows for a variety of delimiters, disallowing only the usage of "... non-alphanumeric, non-backslash, non-whitespace" characters; see [here](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php).

Thus all of the following are valid examples:

```
<?php

$test = "dark gray squirrel";

$r = "!s.+!";

$r2 = "{s.+}";

$r3 = "~s.+~";

preg_match( $r,$test,$matches );
var_dump( $matches );

preg_match( $r2,$test,$matches );
var_dump( $matches );

preg_match( $r3,$test,$matches );
var_dump( $matches );
```

See [live code](https://3v4l.org/h3kbf#output)

Interestingly, Perl affords even greater flexibility than PHP since it supports arbitrary delimiters per its [documentation](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick.html).